# Selecting all records with lcase condition

Tags: mysql

what is the correct syntax to use, for displaying every records in **lower case**
I have used this line `select lcase (*) from table_name;` but i got a syntax error.
Note that the table that I'm using contains numeric columns too.

Comment: shouldn't it be `SELECT LCASE(*) FROM table_name`?

Comment: Tried it but didnt work.@LelioFaieta

Comment: I know it doesn't work. You have to use the function on each string field. But you are also using a mysql function in the wrong way it is not `lcase` but `lcase()` and in the brackets you have to put the name of the field. Have you done a bit of googling on this?

Comment: Got it. I knew that but forgot to add the brackets. yes i have googled it before asking the question because the Stack overflow is intolerant against newbies questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql [LCASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lcase) function, convert STRINGS to lowercase strings.

You must specify for each field of your query which one must be converted.

```
SELECT LCASE(Fiedl1), LCASE(Fiedl2), Field3
FROM   MyTable
```

Comment: So we must specify the fields. Thank you.